# Using information from a congruence to factor a number

Tags: modular-arithmetic, factoring

I am being asked to factor $15347$ given that $7331^2 \equiv 1460^2 \pmod{15347}$. I've tried playing around with each of the numbers -- prime factorization, gcd, lcm, etc., but I can't find a connection that would help me factor $15347$. does anyone have a suggestion as to what to look for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $x^2 - y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)$.  If the product of two numbers is $0$ (mod $n$), but neither is $0$ (mod $n$), what does that tell you?